# python errno 10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, sockets, httplib

New to python. I'm attempting to access the biomedcentral oai interface.

http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/openarchivesprotocol.html#HTTPRequestFormat tells me that all request have to be either HTTP GET or POST requests. I've tried both, going for the simplest possible query that I can come up with (verb=Identify) so as to make sure it's not me incorrectly formatting the query and I get the same error - namely "socket.error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

There's multiple entries on SO for this - they seem to be dealing with either handling the error or be at the socket level of connection, whereas I'm trying to do this with httplib - I'm not doing anything at the socket level.

The code I'm using for the POST method is:

```
import httplib, urllib
params = urllib.urlencode({'verb': "Identify", })
headers = { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Content-Length": 82}

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.biomedcentral.com")
conn.request("POST", "/oai/2.0", params, headers)

response = conn.getresponse()
print (response.status, response.reason)
data = response.read()
conn.close()
```

The get method is simpler:

```
import httplib
connection = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.biomedcentral.com")
connection.request("GET", "/oai/2.0?verb=Identify")
r1 = connection.getresponse()

print (r1.status, r1.reason)
data = r1.read()
print (data)
connection.close()
```

In both cases I'm closing the connection as I think I'm meant to be doing. And I can't see why the server would be closing the connection. It's not intermittent, which is apparently indicative of the website having problems and it occurs when I attempt to access other websites in a similar manner. I've checked with the IT department and my proxy settings appear to be correct. I'm at a loss to think of other causes/solutions.

Anyone got any ideas? They would be much appreciated.

Cheers
Ben.